# Why does type inference behave differently for `HashMap` and my own struct in the presence of a type parameter default?

Tags: rust

I have a struct with two type parameters, one of which has a default type:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Foo<T, F = ()>(PhantomData<(T, F)>);

impl<T, F> Foo<T, F> {
    fn new() -> Self { Self(PhantomData) }
    fn foo(&self, _: T) {}
}


let foo = Foo::new();
foo.foo(0u32);
```

The code above leads to:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:17:15
   |
17 |     let foo = Foo::new();
   |         ---   ^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `F`
   |         |
   |         consider giving `foo` a type
```

I don't understand why the default type is not used here. Note that saying `let foo: Foo<u32> = Foo::new();` already works -- so there is no need to specify the parameter `F`. But why specify `T`? So I was already confused.

But then I remembered that all of this works with `HashMap`! It is defined as `struct HashMap<K, V, S = RandomState>`. And I never needed to specify anything. For example, this works:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

let mut map = HashMap::new();
map.insert(0u32, 'x');
```

([Everything on Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6e3678793832fe846a2f9d189881b857))

**Why is the default type/inference behavior different between `Foo` and `HashMap`?** Does the hashmap use some compiler magic?

Comment: Even `let foo: Foo<_> = Foo::new();` works fine, since `T` can be inferred. This looks like it does not provide any additional information, but in fact it does – explicitly omitting the second parameter to the type constructor tells the compiler to use the default value. The code without any type annotation behaves like `let foo: Foo<_, _> = Foo::new();`, which fails with the same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`HashMap::new` is defined this way:

```
impl<K: Hash + Eq, V> HashMap<K, V, RandomState> {
    pub fn new() -> HashMap<K, V, RandomState> {
        Default::default()
    }
}
```

`RandomState` is provided for `S` for `new`. Your code would look like this for the same behavior:

```
impl<T> Foo<T, ()> {
    fn new() -> Self { Self(PhantomData) }
    fn foo(&self, _: T) {}
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2c479fd1e0ab8a3c8dbdecceddac5ba5)

Note: `Default` can be used for a custom `BuildHasher`:

```
impl<K, V, S> Default for HashMap<K, V, S>
```

Comment: So in short: The `F` that can't be inferred is the parameter `F` to the impl, not the parameter `F` to the struct. If you rename the parameter to the impl to something else, this becomes clear from the error message.

Comment: But this means, that you can't call `new` or `foo` for `F = i32`, correct? Is that possible to achieve?

Comment: @hellow Correct, if `new()` is only defined for `F = ()` you can't call it for other types `F`. If you want to allow that as well you need to add another more flexible method with a different name, or use `Default::default()` as `HashMap` does.